# multiple Notification in android

Tags: android

i want to create reminder application...I am using Notification Manager...
I am using this line as instantiate of Notification...

```
long when=sdf.parse("09 06 2010 15:45:00");
Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.reminder_1,"Reminder",when.getTime());
```

I need to start the notification at specified time...but here it is notification started immediately when i gave the date...and also help  me to show multiple notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `when` argument is a time for the `Notification` which is displayed when the notification bar is in expanded view.  It is not used for scheduling when the `Notification` is displayed.

If you want to schedule something to happen in the future try the [the `AlarmManager` service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: ok i am using alarm manager...it will be scheduled...if the device was rebooted...can the alarm activity correctly process that schedule?

Answer (score 0):

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.update;
        CharSequence tickerText = "assignments";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification assignmentNotification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        assignmentNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
        assignmentNotification.vibrate = vibrate;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "check assignments";
        CharSequence contentText = "chek ur app for assignments ";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ViewAssignmentnotificationActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent,0);
        assignmentNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
       ** final int id = 2;
```

Use another "id" for multiple notifiucation...